# How to sort documents in MongoDB - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb

I have a bunch of documents inside my MongoDB collection. I did write an aggregation code to find and filter some documents. All is well but the result is shown randomly.

[The result is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4UX64.png), you see that entities and chat sources are shown in random order.

The desired result is to show the entities and chat sources in ascending order like the following:

```
Entity 1 Chat Source 1
Entity 1 Chat Source 2
Entity 1 Chat Source 3

Entity 2 Chat Source 1
Entity 2 Chat Source 2
Entity 2 Chat Source 3

Entity 3 Chat Source 1
Entity 3 Chat Source 2
Entity 3 Chat Source 3
```

I tried two ways to sort.

The first way, inside the aggregation code:

```
if total_messages > 0:
    agg_result = mycol.aggregate([
        {
            "$match": {
                "creation_date_time": {"$gte": start, "$lt": end}
            }
        },
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {"Entity": "$entity", "Chat Source": "$chat_source"},
                "Count": {"$sum": 1},
                "Latest Message Date Time": {"$last": "$date_time"}
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {"entity": -1, "chat_source": -1}
        }
    ])
```

This changed nothing and gave the same previous output.

The second way is using pymongo sorting:

```
for response in agg_result:
    doc = mycol.find().sort("entity", pymongo.ASCENDING)
    print(doc)
```

And this gave the following result:

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000027A59AF9850>
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000027A59AF9700>
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000027A59AF9850>
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000027A59AF9700>
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000027A59AF9850>
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000027A59AF9700>
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000027A59AF9850>
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000027A59AF9700>
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x0000027A59AF9850>
```

How can I solve this issue?

[Two examples of the documents that I'm working on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PribX.png)

Comment: Welcome!   Could you provide 2 examples of the input docs on which you are operating?    It helps others really understand what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that instead of

```js
        {
            "$group": {
                "_id": {"Entity": "$entity", "Chat Source": "$chat_source"},
                "Count": {"$sum": 1},
                "Latest Message Date Time": {"$last": "$date_time"}
            }
        },
        {
            "$sort": {"entity": -1, "chat_source": -1}
        }
```

what you mean to do is sort on the grouped `Entity+Chat Source` combination.  After the `$group` stage, there will be no fields `entity` and `chat_source` upon which to sort.  Try:

```js
        {
            "$sort": {"_id.Entity":1, "_id.Chat Source":1}
        }
```

Also note that your pipeline assumes that after the first `$match`, material is flowing into the `$group` stage in ascending datetime order hence the use of `$last` -- but perhaps you mean `$creation_date_time`...?  Unless there are truly two fields `date_time` and `creation_date_time`.

```js
    "Latest Message Date Time": {"$last": "$creation_date_time"}
```

Comment: Exactly, there are two fields. And I truly thank you for the sorting solution! You saved my life! @Buzz Moschetti

Comment: @Anastasia Very good -- in that case don't be shy about marking it as the Accepted Answer.

Comment: Immideately! Thank you again God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

Your sort must be on a field passed from the previous stage of the pipeline, so in your case change the sort to (something like):

```
{ 
    "$sort": {"_id": -1}
}
```

In the second example you have misunderstood how the `.sort()` operator works, hence the unexpected results.

Comment: Thank you so much! Amazing line. @Belly Buster